# Bootstrap Material design floating labels overlap input text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design, mdbootstrap

I am using bootstrap material design and my labels overlap my input texts when the text is pre-populated.. (ref. my screenshot below). Is there a way I can prevent the label from overlapping?

[image]

My code:

```
<div className="modal-body">
    <div className="md-form">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={ project.name } ref="name"/>
        <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div className="md-form">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={ project.description } ref="description"/>
        <label>Description</label>
    </div>
    <div className="md-form">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={ project.slug } ref="slug"/>
        <label>Slug</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

`translateY()` value will change the position of label when input is active or focused. You can manipulate its value to set the desired position of label and also you can change the font-size value.

HTML:

```
<div className="md-form">            
        <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={ project.name } ref="name"/>    
        <label>Name</label>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.md-form label.active {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    transform: translateY(-140%);
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi - this results in a little less overlap, but it's still overlapping..

Comment: Earlier i assumed that you are using [fezvrasta material design library](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/). Since you are using [mdbootstrap](http://mdbootstrap.com/components/forms/). your earlier syntax were correct. Can your replicate your problem in jsfiddle or codepen. I have created the codepen example everything work fine there. check the codepen **[link](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/QKKQpZ?editors=1100)**

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and fixed by using focused class on element. If you are using `vuejs` you can use inline statement to check if the value is filled and then call `focused` class (using `v-bind:class`) that will set style for the element.

Something like this:

```
<div class="form-line"  v-bind:class="[name != null ? 'focused' : '']">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name">
     <label class="form-label" >Name</label>
</div>
```

P.S. This also can be used for other frameworks with appropriate syntax.

Comment: This is working well, I'm using is-filled in vue instead of focused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular2 then you can do this with out creating a custom directive.  On the label do something like this.

```
<label [class.active]="name && name.length > 0">Some Label</label>
```

Comment: Does this method even work? For some reason my active class keeps getting removed from the label.

Comment: @Neve12ende12, It should still work.  You just need to make sure bootstrap is using the active css class.

Comment: You are correct, I must have just did something wrong.  In VueJS it is something like v-bind:class="[name ? active: '']"

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Material input -->
<div class="md-form">
  <input value="John Doe" type="text" id="myid" class="form-control">
  <label for="myid">Example label</label>
</div>
```

Source: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/inputs/